# How to correctly enable pylint with ALE in Vim?

Tags: python-3.x, macos, vim, vim-plugin

I want to set up python linting in Vim using the ALE Vim-package. So far it works well in Atom using the Atom-Plugin, but in Vim it somehow is not working. I installed

- pylint using pip3,
- Vim 8.1 and
- ALE using the Vundle Plugin-Manager.

In my .vimrc I set the

```
let g:ale_linters={
'python': ['pylint'],
.....+other languages....
}
```

option. Additionally I read the ALE docs and also tried setting the following:

```
let g:ale_python_executable='python3'
let g:ale_python_pylint_use_global=1
```

ALE gets installed correctly and works for Javascript, but for Python, there is just nothing happening. 
In case of incorrect code (missing ")") like:

```
print("Hi"
```

nothing is marked as error.

It would be great if someone knows how to set this up and can provide some help! Thanks.

Comment: Maybe report the output of `:ALEInfo` in the vim command to check how ALE is configured for the current file?

Comment: Well, just following the steps you put in the question fixed the problem I was having, which was that ALE/pylint apparently wasn't seeing the packages I've installed in my venv. So, thanks for the well written, well researched question!

Answer (score 4):

I was able to get this working, with the following steps:

1. install pylint

   `python3 -m pip install pylint`

   At least for my setup there was a warning:

   > Installing collected packages: pylint
   >
   > WARNING: The scripts epylint, pylint, pyreverse and symilar are
   > installed in '/home/vagrant/.local/bin' which is not on PATH.

   so then:
2. Add `pylint` to `$PATH`

   `export PATH="$HOME/.local/bin:$PATH"`

   (this can be added to ~/.profile to be configured persistently)

   At you should be able to run `pylint` manually:

   ```
   $ cat syntaxerr.py
   print("hi
   $ pylint syntaxerr.py
   ************* Module syntaxerr
   syntaxerr.py:1:10: E0001: EOL while scanning string literal (, line 1) (syntax-error)
   ```
3. Install ALE

   `git clone https://github.com/dense-analysis/ale.git ~/.vim/pack/git-plugins/start/ale`

At this point the syntax check is working as long as syntax is enabled:

```
$ cat .vimrc
syntax on
```

If you'd like to configure `g:ale_linters`, note that you must escape the newline to create a multi-line dictionary:

```
let g:ale_linters={
\ 'python': ['pylint'],
\}
```

Finally, to see how ALE is currently configured, you can always run the following command:

```
:ALEInfo
```

Comment: Thanks, I needed to add my linter to $PATH!